# Moment Generating Function property for $M_{X-Y}(t)$ the same as $M_{X+Y}(t)$?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I know that if $X,Y$ independent, then the moment generating function ($M_{X+Y}(t)$)

$M_{X+Y}(t) = M_X(t)  M_Y(t)$ is true.

Where $M_{X}(t)$ is the moment generating function of $x$ and $M_{Y}(t)$ is the moment generating function of $y$.

But what about the case of

$M_{X-Y}(t) =$ ?

A simple explanation or proof would help greatly! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $M_{X}(s)$ and $M_{X}(s,t)$?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I will edit my post.

Comment: I meant, can you explain how you are defining "joint moment generating function"?

Comment: $M_{X}(t) = E[e^{tx}]$

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by $E$?

Comment: expected value is E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_{X-Y}(t) = \frac{M_X(t)}{M_Y(t)}$, under some mild assumptions about zeros.  You can prove this by setting $Y = -Z$, where $Z$ is some random variable, and using your observation about $M_{X,Z}$.